# setup initial option value to --select-- while rendering dynamic value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Expected to have one more option --Select Option-- initally then allow one, two three option in reactjs here is my fiddle

```
function GetListItems(props) {
    const numbers = props.numbers;
      const listItems = numbers.map((number, index) =>{
          return(

                    <option key={number}>
                        {number}
                    </option>
                )
      })
      return (
        <select>{listItems}</select>
      );

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7L3xmqt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this option to your array.

```
const records = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
const recordsWithInitialValue = ["--Select Option--"].concat(records);
```